# How Can I Save Animation.Artist animation?

Tags: python, windows-xp, matplotlib

I have a problem:

My program is working well but when I try to save the animation that I plot, The compiler responds with an error.

The Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig=plt.figure()
for infile in glob.glob('*.png'):
    img=mpimg.imread(infile)
    imgplot=plt.imshow(img)
    im_list2.append([imgplot])
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, im_list2, interval=50, blit=True)
```

But when I try to save it like this:

```
ani.save('Animation1.mp4')
```

It returns an error:

> WindowsError: [Error 2] The system could not find the given data.

Comment: I you provide a complete minimal example demonstrating the problem, it'd be much easier to answer.

Comment: If you have found the answer to your question (as given in your comment to the answer by india_dourada) you should answer your own question and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are with the same problem I had few days ago: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213554/matplotlib-animation-error-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified) is the question I posted!

I solved my problem by changing line 163 from C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py from

```
proc = Popen(command, shell=False, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

to

```
proc = Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

...However, I am not sure how "safe" is this change in the animation.py file!
[See more info here](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

Comment: In my case, I had no aditional trouble. My animation was properly saved in the path it was supposed to.
Do you know in which directory are you working on?
I suggest that you choose your directory in the beginning of your script (for example, if you have a folder named D:/CG/DREAM):
`os.chdir('D:/CG/DREAM')`
Then, check if the animation is saved on this folder.

Comment: No I had to add to the python path an application called ffmpeg.exe (http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/), and then it works well ;) (Also without changing from False to True like you suggested)