# How to set ffmpeg for matplotlib in mac os x

Tags: python, matplotlib, ffmpeg, osx-mountain-lion, enthought

I want to animate some plots with matplotlib. The version I have is the Enthough Canopy distribution (Version: 1.1.0.1371), running in a mac os x 10.8 (Mountain Lion). I have used the FuncAnimation routine from the animation package of matplotlib. My problem comes saving the animation. I want to save in mp4 format:

```
anim.save('test.mp4',fps=30)
```

The error I get is:

```
UserWarning: MovieWriter ffmpeg unavailable 
warnings.warn("MovieWriter %s unavailable" % writer)
```

So I installed ffmpeg via Macports. But I am still having the same error. Do you know how to setup matplotlib in order to recognise ffmpeg? Do I have to change the matplotlibrc file?
Thanks.

EDIT: I have realized that I can manually put '/opt/local/bin' in the PYTHONPATH, but it does not change the PATH in Enthough Canopy. Do anyone know how to change the PATH in canopy?

Comment: Is `ffmpeg` in path? If you type `ffmpeg` in console, does it runs?

Comment: Yes, it runs. I double-checked that the PATH is OK and the program runs.

Comment: Regarding changing PATH and other env vars on OSX: https://support.enthought.com/entries/23665767-How-do-I-set-PYTHONPATH-and-other-environment-variables-for-Canopy-

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. I saw your post, and I have tried that. The strange thing is that the python from my terminal load the full path, whereas the python at the editor in canopy only loads a shorter path. Why? I would like to know where the canopy editor loads the variable `os.environ['PATH']`. What is the difference between run ipython from the terminal and run it from the canopy editor?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. My solution was very simple.

Download the binary from [here](http://ffmpegmac.net).

Then do

```
sudo mv ~/Downloads/ffmpeg /usr/bin/
```

Comment: If you're going to go this route, I would strongly suggest adding ffmeg to your usr/local/bin. It's general good unix/linux practice to not modify your usr/bin directory.

Answer (score 4):

I had success when installing with homebrew:
`brew install ffmpeg`

After that set up the FFMpegWriter yourself by:

```
mywriter = animation.FFMpegWriter()
anim.save('mymovie.mp4',writer=mywriter)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution can be found in the workaround in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213554/matplotlib-animation-error-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256829/how-can-i-save-animation-artist-animation/9281433#9281433) post.

It seems that the path of the shell is not loaded by matplotlib, and since macports are installed in `/opt/local/bin`, `ffmpeg` can't be found.

Either go for the hack described above, try making a symlink in `/bin` for `ffmpeg`, or try adding the path to `ffmpeg` to the python path as suggested in the comments of the second link

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have tried the solution of the second post, and include a launch.conf file. It changed the PYTHONPATH variable, but when I type `os.environ['PATH']`,the path `/opt7local/bin` is not there. So I get the same error.

Comment: which launch.conf are you talking about? try something like `sudo ln -s /opt/local/bin/ffmpeg /usr/bin/ffmpeg`

Answer (score 0):

If you are agnostic to the movie file type, you could use the Python `cv2` library to write .avi movie files from a folder of the images you wish to combine into a movie. Here's an example:

```
import cv2 

# Create avi movie from static plots created of each time slice
image_folder = 'path_to_png_files'
video_name = '/mov-{}.avi'.format('optional label')

# Store individual frames into list
images = [img for img in os.listdir(image_folder) if img.endswith(".png")]

# Create frame dimension and store its shape dimensions
frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, images[0]))
height, width, layers = frame.shape

# cv2's VideoWriter object will create a frame 
video = cv2.VideoWriter(avi_path + video_name, 0, 1, (width,height))

# Create the video from individual images using for loop
for image in images:
    video.write(cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, image)))

# Close all the frames
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Release the video write object
video.release()
```